# Why method setValue of Firebase restart my game activity?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, setvalue

I am trying to develop a multiplayer version of arkanoid for android device , but i am stuck .

This is the repository , in case you want to look closer to it :

https://github.com/SmsArkanoid/Arkanoid-android-game-master .

The problem is into GameMulti.java and PlayMulti.java .
I did create a room where two player can play together ( will play together ).

I ve created a function update that refresh the position of the object on the screen : ball , paddle , brick ecc.

For now my aim was to update the score on the firebase database.
The score is separated between player1 and player2 . So i do this using the database reference to the score and set value. This works , except that as the value is updated , the activity reset and the game restart .

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Brick b = list.get(i);
                int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 10);
                for (Ball ball : balls){
                    if (ball.suddenlyBrick(b.getX(), b.getY())) {
                        list.remove(i);
                        contatore--;
                        guarateed_upg++;
                        this.score +=  80;
                        pointReference.setValue(score);
                        if((random<=2 || guarateed_upg == 10)&& upgrades.isEmpty()) {
                            tipo = (int) (1 + Math.random()*3);
                            Log.i("the random number is" , ""+tipo);
                            if(upgrades.isEmpty()){
                                upgrades.add(new Upgrade(b.getX(), b.getY(), 10, context , tipo));
                            }
                            guarateed_upg =0;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The structure of the database is Room - > Player 1 -> Score . The same for player2 who's connected to the same room .

Thank you in advance for whoever will help me .
I hope i ve explained my problem clearly enough .

Answer (score 0):

Finally , i solved my problem .

It was a problem related to the activity which created rooms for the game .

Into this activity there was an ValueEventListener which remained open and into the block of the method onchange the game activity was launched .

So as the game started , the database was updated , a new activity was called.

So the solution was to close the ValueEventListener on the other activity .